# Test if a network is online by using urllib2

Tags: python, networking

**My concerns:**

1. Is the code pythonic
2. Is the code practical

I tend on expanding the usefulness of this script, if you don't think it's stupid idea. One thing I will implement is command-line arguments by way of argparse.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


'''
Test if network is online by sending and http request to a remote
web-server. I wrote this because my network connection sucks.
'''

import urllib2
import sys


def is_online(**kwargs):
    '''
    Determine weather or not your network is online
    by sending a HTTP GET request. If the network is
    online the function will return true. If the network
    is not online the function will return false
    '''

    # Set the default request time out.
    # This will be passed as a keyword argument
    # to urllib2.urlopen.
    kwargs.setdefault('timeout', 0.30)
    kwargs.setdefault('url', 'http://www.google.com')
    timeout = kwargs.get('timeout')
    url = kwargs.get('url')

    try:
        print 'Sending request to {}'.format(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception:
        # Generally using a catch-all is a bad practice but
        # I think it's ok in this case
        response = False
        print 'Request to {} failed'.format(url)
    if response:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    '''
    Continually check if the network is online.
    If the network is online stop checking.
    '''
    while True:
        if is_online():
            print 'Net is up'
            break
        else:
            print 'Net down.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 7):

I would use Python's socket library instead of urllib. Then, you could test like this:

```
import socket
REMOTE_SERVER = "www.google.com"
def is_connected():
  try:
    host = socket.gethostbyname(REMOTE_SERVER)
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    return True
  except:
     pass
  return False
print is_connected()
```

<sub>Borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20913928/3296811)</sub>

---

I think the most obvious thing to point out is this:

> ```
> if response:
>     return True
> else:
>     return False
> ```

You can actually just `return` the variable, so just `return response` would replace all those lines.

---

There's not really any reason to use `.format` for one variable.

> ```
> 'Sending request to {}'.format(url)
> ```

Plain string concatenation is fine, *for one variable*.

---

Anyway, what's the point of printing out that you're requesting `google.com`?

> ```
> 'Request to {} failed'.format(url)
> ```

The level of abstraction that you put into this, is that it'll return whether you're connected or not.

Printing out anything other than: `'Net is up'` or `'Net down'` (*Which could better be*: `'Net is down, retrying connection'`) seems superfluous.

---

> ```
> kwargs.setdefault('timeout', 0.30)
> ```

I would avoid the magic numbers (undefined numbers: `0.30`), define it as a constant (in all caps) to improve readability.

---

> Is this code Pythonic?

I'd recommend reading PEP8, Python's official style guide. It has many guidelines to follow on just about everything; it should really be a Python programmer's Bible. There's also a nice little [Online PEP8 checker](http://pep8online.com) to help/show you where your code doesn't meet the standards of PEP8.

The term 'Pythonic' is not so easily defined, so I'm not really going to give you a 'Yes or No' answer, but, I'd just really recommend reading over PEP8.

> Is this code practical?

Yes, it's practical.

However, one thing more to point out; While you keep retrying and retrying:

- Put a some kind of wait in between network connection tests.
- Every time you call `is_online`, when the `Net is down`, you redo the `url` setup, consider keeping that seperate so you can only do the bare minimum for the continual tests:

> ```
> kwargs.setdefault('timeout', 0.30)
> kwargs.setdefault('url', 'http://www.google.com')
> timeout = kwargs.get('timeout')
> url = kwargs.get('url')
> ```

Comment: Nicely done, I especially like the part about the mismatched level of abstraction. Though, I'd say the OP's dependency on urllib2 is not practical, when the job can be done without it

Comment: Is there any other way to check internet running status. Because if you pining `google.com` again again, then they will block our IP. So Is there any other way.?

Answer (score 2):

This `try`/`except` block serves no purpose.

```
try:
    print 'Sending request to {}'.format(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

When the user presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> the program will exit. There is no need to catch the error and then manually exit with `sys.exit`.

Comment: Won't it suppress the traceback usually associated with a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception?